# How to repeat input command if user input is invalid with a string variable - C++

Tags: c++, string, loops, if-statement, user-input

So I have very little coding experience and the code I wrote has this problem of asking the user to input again if correctly choosing "yes" the first time. It works correctly if the user inputs "no" or if the user writes an invalid option, the next set of questions would work. I haven't found any examples dealing with string variables without using arrays. Thanks - 
P.S. I know its crappy form but I'm just trying to get it to work.

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string choice;

    cout<<"Do you choose to go fight in the war??\n\n";
    cout << "choose yes or no\n";
    cin >> choice;

    while(choice != "yes" || choice != "no")
    {
        cout << "pls enter again\n";
        cin >> choice;
        if(choice == "no") 
        {
            cout << "you live";
            break;
        }
        else(choice == "yes");
        {
            cout << "you die";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `else` you need `else if`:

```
else if (choice == "yes") {
  cout << "you die";
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use an infinite loop to handle the input. If a valid input is given, break the loop.

```cpp
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string choice;

    cout << "Do you choose to go fight in the war??\n\n";
    cout << "choose yes or no\n";

    while (true) {
        cin >> choice;
        if (choice == "no") {
            cout << "you live";
            break;
        }
        else if (choice == "yes")
        {
            cout << "you die";
            break;
        }
        else {
            cout << "pls enter again\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I started learning coding, I faced the same logic problems like what you are struggling at the moment. I just think that you are having problems with syntax and coding logic. Hope that my code can somehow help!

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;

 int main() {
   string choice;

   do {
       cout << "Do you choose to go fight in the war??\n";
       cout << "Choose yes or no\n";
       cin >> choice;

       if (choice == "no") {

        cout << "you live\n";
        break;

       } else if (choice == "yes") {

        cout << "you die\n";
        break;
       }

   } while (choice != "yes" && choice != "no");

   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use do- while loop for string input and after the loop apply conditions

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    String choice;
    cout << "Do you choose to go fight in the war??\n\n";
    cout << "choose yes or no\n";
    do
    {
        cin >> choice;
        If(choice != "yes" || choice != "no") 
              Cout<<"please enter again";
     }
     while (choice != "yes" || choice != "no");
     If (choice == "no")
    {
          cout << "you live";
     } 
    else
    {
          cout << "you die";
     }

}
```